# MySQL 5.5 automatic timestamp update to current

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, migration

So the timestamp containing column in my database gets automatically updated to current timestamp when I update data there, even if I don't pass any timestamps (not passing *null*, but just ignoring this field, not including it in update array).

I have checked table structure and discovered that the timestamp column settings are set to "`default - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" and "on update - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`", but I've never written statements like these in my migrations and I don't need any automatic update to current timestamp (in my migration files, from which the database was created, there are just rows like `$table->timestamp('date');`).

And so here is the question: what should be written in migration files to avoid this situation and why does it even appear? Is this some kind of MySQL feature, or does MySQL interpret ignored field like passed *null*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found solution in MySQL docs, it is said that no specifications in migration is equal to specifying current_timestamp on default and update, so to avoid my issue I have to specify default value in migration, and do not specify update attribute.
Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html